# jquery find any child with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to determine if there is a div with an id below a set parent.

Condition1:

```
<div id="top">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Condition2:

```
<div id="top">
<div></div>
<div id="something"></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to know if the element top has any div's with an assigned id as any child.

I've been trying along the lines of the following.

```
var test = $('#top').find('id');
```

But I keep getting the same result no matter if there is a div with an id or not.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var childrenWithId = $('#top [id]');
```

The `[xx]` selector tests for the presence of an attribute xx. What your code does is look for an `<id>` element.

EDIT: You can even be specific as to what kind of tag you want:

```
var divsWithId = $("#top div[id]");
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean `var test = $('#top').find('#id')?`

Comment: @Kolink: I meant #id = #hisId

Comment: Still, the OP isn't looking for a specific ID, just an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all the divs and check its id value like here:

```
$("#top").find("div").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
    if(id.length > 0){
        alert("ID " + id + " is set.");
    }
})
```

Comment: Yeah actually... but what if the id has been set but is empty string? The [xx] selector will still select it.

Comment: Nobody in their right mind would do that, though, so it's not really anything to worry about.